# ffmpeg : how to reduce bit rate of transport stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm aiming to reduce the bit rate of a video contained in a transport stream.
The command (ffmpe.exe) is as follows :

```
ffmpeg -i "udp://127.0.0.1:40101" -map 0:v -c:v libx264 -b:v 256k -maxrate 256k -bufsize 256k -map 0:d -c copy -f mpegts "udp://127.0.0.1:10101"
```

The result is a tranport stream with the same bit rate.
What I'm doing wrong?
Thank you.
sb

Answer (score 0):

Place the `-c copy` before `-c:v libx264`. See https://superuser.com/a/1219824